# UITableViewCell subviews are displaying outside of cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In a section of my UITableView, there are 5 cells, three of which have been configured to expand/collapse to provide a more detailed view when selected. One of these cells shows a diagram of a number of small squares, which displays perfectly, until another cell is expanded, like this:

[image: Working Cell]

When the cell is collapsed, however, the subviews in the cell display in different cells, in different sections, like this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

To create the subviews in the cell, this is my code in the cellForRow method, which just uses an array of UIViews:

```
for vote in vote_array {
    cell.contentView.addSubview(vote as? UIView ?? UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)))
            }
```

I tried removing all the subviews before I added them by doing this, but it doesn't change anything:

```
for subview in cell.contentView.subviews {
                subview.removeFromSuperview()
            }
```

Edit: This is inside a switch statement, but here is the relevant cell/case cellForRow:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = true
            cell.clipsToBounds = true
            let vote_array = getVoteArray()

            for subview in cell.contentView.subviews {
                subview.removeFromSuperview()
            }

            for case let vote as UIView in vote_array {
                cell.contentView.addSubview(vote)
            }
```

Edit: 
The core of getVoteArray:

```
func getVoteArray() -> NSMutableArray {
    var i = 0
    var x = 20
    var y = 4
    let blockViews : NSMutableArray = []
    for color in blocks {
        let block = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: x, y: y, width: 20, height: 20))
        block.backgroundColor = color as? UIColor
        blockViews.add(block)
        x = x + 24
        i = i + 1
        if i == num_blocks_per_row { i = 0; y = y + 24; x = 20 }
    }
    diagramHeight = y + 24
    return blockViews
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why the subviews are generating randomly all over the tableView.

Comment: You dequeue the cell first ? But do you remove all subviews before adding a new one ? If not, you may keep several views.

Comment: Note: could replace CGRect.int() by CGRect.zeo. Faster to type and read.

Comment: @claude31 Before I add the subviews I do this to remove them:
                    for subview in cell.contentView.subviews {                   
                    subview.removeFromSuperview()
                    }

Comment: Could you post the complete code for cellAtRow.

Comment: yes, just edited @claude31

Comment: Thanks. Not sure of this, but vote_array is an array of UIViews. Exact ? Hence, they are references to UIViews (would need to see getVoteArray(): do you create new UIView instances or use already created ?). If the later, then when you add Subview, you remove all other links to any superview. [ see doc on addSubview: Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous superview before making the receiver its new superview.]

Comment: @claude31It is an array of UIViews, and I do create new instances, I'll add the getVoteArray code to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up adding

```
for case let cell as UITableViewCell in tableView.subviews {
    for subview in cell.contentView.subviews {
        if subview.tag == 115 {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

to my `didSelectRowAt` method, after adding the tag when each view is created. I'm still not sure why the views were being added to different cells, but this got rid of them at least.

Comment: the views were being added to different cells because they are being reused. The view from `indexPath(row: 0, section: 0)` could be reused for `indexPath(row: 1, section: 0)`. I suggest you subclass `UITableViewCell` so you don't have to do `subview.removeFromSuperview()`

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement unique **ReuseIdentifiers** for collapsed and expanded states.

If the cell is collapsed then don't load all those views in it by dequeuing a collapsedCell where the height of all those UIViews is either 0 or they are not added to subview.

If the cell is expanded than deque a expandedCell where the views are layed out as in the first screenshot.

After expanding and or collapsing call **tableview.reloadData()**

Answer (score 0):

It used to be a long long time ago that UIViews clipped their children, but that hasn't been true for a very long time.  If you want clipping on you need to either change [UIView.clipsToBounds](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622415-clipstobounds) to true or use the underlying CALayer property maskToBounds.

```
cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Or you can check the box in the storyboard/nib.